# Multiply two arrays of unequal size java

Tags: java, arrays

```
int a[]={1,1,2,2};

int b[]={1,1,1,1,3,3,2,2};

int ab[]=new int[b.length];
```

I want to Multiply  `ab[]= a[]* b[]`

`ab []` should be like that `= {1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4}`

i try for loop but i don't know how to do it while the two array size are not equal

Comment: Could you elaborate on your multiplication process?

Comment: What kind of logic do  you use for this multiplication?

Comment: Loop on array `b`, and use the modulo with the size of array `a` to give position of multiplier in array `a` (I'm supposing a0*b0, a1*b1, ..., a0*b4, a1*b5, ..., so you go once through array `b`, but go through array `a`in a loop until you go through `b`once).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int a[]={1,1,2,2};
int b[]={1,1,1,1,3,3,2,2};
int ab[]=new int[b.length];

for (int i=0 ; i<b.length ; i++) {
    ab[i] = b[i] * a[i%a.length];
}
```

This should give you the right result. But I don't check for array lengths, or make sure that array `b` is longer than array `a`, so think of doing that beforehand.

Comment: This worked for me thanks

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean ab[] = {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4}? That would make it the size of b.

Assuming that once you get to index 4 in b, you want to loop back to index 0 in a while multiplying, this should be fairly straightforward to code up - I've coded it up using C++ 14. It should be fairly adaptable to Java.

Here is the output: C: {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4}

```
// Sample program to print out the product of two arrays
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int a[] = {1, 1, 2, 2};
    int b[] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2};

    constexpr auto lengthA = std::extent<decltype(a)>::value;
    constexpr auto lengthB = std::extent<decltype(b)>::value;

    int c[lengthB] = { 0 };

    static_assert(lengthB > lengthA, "Length of b is expected to be greater than length of a!");

    int indexA = 0;
    for (int indexB = 0; indexB < lengthB; ++indexB)
    {
        c[indexB] = a[indexA] * b[indexB];

        indexA = (indexA + 1) % lengthA;
    }

    // Lets print out the resultant array
    std::cout << "C: {";
    for (int indexC = 0; indexC < lengthB; ++indexC)
    {
        std::cout << c[indexC];

        if (indexC < lengthB - 1)
        {
            std::cout << ", ";
        }
    }
    std::cout << "}" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: At the risk of writing some code that doesn't compile, here's the theoretically sound, but unbuilt Java code (just the part that really matters):

```
int a[]={1,1,2,2};
int b[]={1,1,1,1,3,3,2,2};
int ab[]=new int[b.length];

int indexA = 0;
for (int indexB = 0; indexB < b.length; ++indexB)
{
    ab[indexB] = b[indexB]*a[indexA];
    indexA = (indexA + 1) % a.length;
}

// At this point, ab should have what you need
```

Comment: Whilst I agree with the logic, your answer is in `C++`, question is tagged `Java`.

Comment: Agree - didn't have Java on my dev machine unfortunately (didn't want to post something that doesn't compile). But I think porting this should be pretty easy.

Comment: Yeah, when that happens to my I just put a small code sample, not a full executable. Still, easy to convert, just need to use `a.length` and `b.length` and so on.

Comment: thank for answer but i don't understand C++

Comment: Hey @john, I've added a sample Java implementation.